# Adding input tag in json file

Tags: json

I would like to know whether is it possible to insert an input tag in Json file? I would like to add a checkbox in `here`

```
{
     "data1":"here"
}
```

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org/) doesn't have "tags"

Comment: Looking at the answer you accepted, you should probably define your question a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"row"[{ 
   "DATA1" ："<input type='checkbox'/>" 
},
{ 
   "DATA2" ："<input type='text'/>" 
}
]}
```

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The closest you could get would probably be to represent a checkbox as a string.

```
{
    "data1":"<input type=\"checkbox\"/>"
}
```

Then you would be able to insert that string as html into the DOM somewhere (assuming this is for an HTML webpage)

```
document.getElementById("someid").innerHTML = myJSONObject.data1;
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you might be able to use a function that returns a checkbox.

```
{
    "data1":function(){ 
        var box = document.createElement("input");
        box.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        return box;
    }
}
```

Then in your code that parses the JSON you would need to call the data1 property as a function

```
var myCheckboxFromJSONFile = myJSONObject.data1();
```

Answer (score -1):

I had found the solution.
Hopefully it can help any newbies outside

```
{
      "data1":"<input type='checkbox'>"
}
```

Don't use double quotes(`"`) use single quotes(`'`)

Comment: or escape your quotes
"<input type=\"checkbox\"  />"